# Formal Treatment of Knights and Knaves?

Tags: logic, soft-question, puzzle, book-recommendation

[Knights and Knaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_and_Knaves) are a variant of logic puzzles involving figuring out a solution to some logical constraints.

Is there a book which treats these issues formally, in detail? I am hoping it would formalize the notion of propositions, predicates and talk about second order logic (where knights and knaves start referring to their own statements) and possibly even deducing solutions with something like Prolog, or formalizing them in something like Coq

Comment: [What is the name of this book?](https://www.amazon.com/What-Name-This-Book-Recreational/dp/0486481980/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1497146734&sr=8-1&keywords=what+is+the+name+of+this+book).

Comment: The "self referential" part of the knights and knaves problem isn't second order logic, still just plain old simple propositional logic.

Comment: @vadim123 I don't see any formalization there. Did you mean "Forever Undecided"?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://dcproof.com/LiarParadox2.htm It isn't about Knight and Knaves, It is about the original all-Cretans-are-Liars paradox. Yes, it makes use of a "truth" predicate T, but it seems to work.